# Google Presentation converted to PowerPoint presentation fonts look different

Tags: google-slides

I want to download a Google Presentation as a PowerPoint presentation. I want the PowerPoint presentation to be the exact copy of the Google one except the fact that it is a PowerPoint file.

I was able to download the Google one into a PowerPoint with **File > Download as > Microsoft PowerPoint(.pptx)** option from my Google Presentation window. But the downloaded presentation appears to be different from the original presentation.

The fonts of the downloaded presentation is not the same as the original Google Presentation.

> **Original Font:**
>
> [image: GOOGLE PRESENTATION FONT - IMAGE]
>
> **Downloaded Font:**
>
> [image: POWERPOINT PRESENTATION FONT - IMAGE]

Please help me to download an exact copy of my Google Presentation as a PowerPoint presentation.

---

**PostScript:** I googled about [downloading google presentation](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=download%20google%20presentation&oq=download%20google%20presentation&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l4.6950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). But the search results weren't helpful.

Comment: What is the name of the font on Google Presentation and do you have the same font installed on your computer?

Comment: It shows **Autowide** in google and **Arial** in powerpoint.

Comment: Download and install the Autowide font if you can. Then see if it is the same result

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: Thank you. Your idea worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have the correct and matching fonts installed on your local computer.

If you download a presentation and the fonts do not look the same, or the computer changes them to something else, you need to go back to the Google Presentation and find out the font name of the text that looks different.

Then you need to download and install the relevant/missing fonts on your computer. After that, the Presentation will look like it did.